# Creating an array of objects and dynamically instantiating them in a while loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to create an array of objects for an assignment in Javascript, but the following doesn't seem to work

```
var employee = {
employeeId: "",
hoursWorked: 0,
overtimeWorked: 0,
wage: 15
};

var employees = [];
var p = 0;
var i = 0;
while(p != -1){
    p = prompt("please enter employee id#")
    employees[i] = new employee();
    employees[i].employeeId = p;
    i++
}
```

I've gone through and comment debugged my code and the problem seems to be

```
employees[i] = new employee();
```

Whether or not I do this outside the loop, or with any element in the array, I don't seem to be able to instantiate any elements of the array as the employee object.

Comment: Learn more about `new`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `new` with a constructor function.  So, you need to change your `employee` variable into a constructor function.

```
function Employee() {
    this.employeeId = "";
    this.hoursWorked = 0;
    this.overtimeWorked = 0;
    this.wage = 15;
};
```

Then, you can do:

```
employees[i] = new Employee();
```

and get a new employee object each time.

---

In your specific case, I'd suggest allowing the constructor to take an argument too and fixing up your `while` loop to handle cancel of the user prompt appropriately:

```
function Employee(id) {
    this.employeeId = id;
    this.hoursWorked = 0;
    this.overtimeWorked = 0;
    this.wage = 15;
};

var employees = [];
var p = 0;
while (true) {
    p = prompt("please enter employee id#");
    if (!p) {
        break;
    }
    employees.push(new Employee(p));
};
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zk7bdfrv/

FYI, your while loop was flawed too because `prompt()` returns `null` when cancelled, not `-1` and you were using the `null` value.

Comment: With my code exactly like yours, the page doesn't seem to work.  it's not letting me use the this keyword doesn't seem to be working when I use it as you have here.  Do I need to do the employee = {}; first and then do function employee(id){};  ?

Comment: @Csteele5 - it seems to work fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zk7bdfrv/ .  You will have to show us the actual code you're using in the context you're using it to know what is wrong.

Comment: I got it working, it was just being finnicky.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Define `employee` as the following :

```
function Employee() {
    this.employeeId = "";
    this.hoursWorked = 0;
    this.overtimeWorked = 0;
    this.wage = 15;
};
```

Then instantiate as :

```
new Employee();
```

It is a best practice to name your constructor functions with an **uppercase first letter**. That way, they differ from other objects and you know you can instantiate them.